# Combine the values of a list and print in table, first_name combines with last_name to form full_name

Tags: python, html, flask

Need to combine the values in the List to display as part of the table, using flask, bootstrap and python.  I have printed the first and last names but I don't know how to combine these values to print.

I have printed the first and last names but I don't know how to combine these values to print Need to print as seen in the images

Python Code added as image

```
  <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Full Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for i in range(0,ln) %}
                <tr> 
                    {% for j in users[i] %}
                        <td>{{ users[i][j] }}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <td>-</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/atCBO.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
{% for i in range(0,ln) %}
      <tr> 
          {% for j in users[i] %}
                <td>{{ users[i][j] }}</td>
          {% endfor %}
                <td>
                     {% for j in users[i] %}
                        {{ users[i][j] }} 
                     {% endfor %}
                </td>
      </tr>
{% endfor %}
```